Does such a factorization exist?
Let $\theta_2,\theta_1$ be two real positive parameters with $\theta_2>\theta_1$ and consider the function \begin{align}F_{\theta_1,\,\theta_2}(x)=x^{\theta_2-\theta_1}\exp\left(-x^{\theta_2}+x^{\theta_1}\right),&&x>0.\end{align}
This function is not monotone, as $$\lim_{x\to0^+}F_{\theta_1,\,\theta_2}(x)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}F_{\theta_1,\,\theta_2}(x)=0.$$
The question is:

Does exist a composition
$$F_{\theta_1,\,\theta_2}=G_{\theta_1,\,\theta_2}\circ T$$of $F_{\theta_1,\,\theta_2}$ into a non-decreasing function $G_{\theta_1,\,\theta_2}$, which depends on the parameters, and another function $T$ which doesn't?

This question arose while looking for a family of distributions which does not have a monotone likelihood ratio in any statistic. I came up with the pdf $f_\theta(x)=\theta x^{\theta-1}e^{-x^\theta}\mathcal I\{x>0\}$.
PS1: I think that the answer is no because the stationary point of $F_{\theta_1,\,\theta_2}$ depends on the parameters, but I cannot think of a way to formalize that.
PS2: I couldn't find a true mathematical definition of a statistic $T(x)$, but I think we can restrict to the case of $T$ measurable, or even continuous if needed.

Do you require $G$ and/or $T$ to be nonnegative?

@Pranay Forgot to mention. The theta  parameters are positive real numbers. I edited the question

@GregMartin Actually, I am looking for a composition of function, not a factorization. I should punctualize that, I guess. We require G, the outer function, to be non-decreasing.

Indeed we can show that there is no composition of the form $F_{\theta_1,\theta_2}=G_{\theta_1,\theta_2}\circ T$ where $T$ is not injective on $(0,\infty)$, regardless of whether $G_{\theta_1,\theta_2}$ is increasing. This is enough to answer the question, since if both $G_{\theta_1,\theta_2}$ and $T$ are injective then $F_{\theta_1,\theta_2}$ would also be, which we know is not true.
Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $F_{\theta_1,\theta_2}=G_{\theta_1,\theta_2}\circ T$ and that $T(x_1)=T(x_2)$ for some $0<x_1<x_2$. Then $F_{1,\theta_2}(x_1) = F_{1,\theta_2}(x_2)$ for all $\theta_2>1$ as well. But
$$
\frac{F_{1,\theta_2}(x_2)}{F_{1,\theta_2}(x_1)} = e^{x_2^{\theta_2} - x_1^{\theta_2} + x_1 - x_2} \biggl( \frac{x_1}{x_2} \biggr)^{\theta_2-1};
$$
and the right-hand side tends to $\infty$ as $\theta_2\to\infty$, so in particular it cannot be identically $1$.

$G_{\theta_1,\theta_2}$ is not required to be strictly increasing, but only non-decreasing, which does not imply injective.

Fair point, but if a nondecreasing function is not injective then it's constant on an interval, which is also incompatible with $F$'s behavior.

I trust you but a clarification of the answer would help (mostly: not injective on $im(T)\implies$ constant on a (non-trivial) subinterval of $im(T)$, but what if $im(T)$ has no such subinterval? does it matter?).

The only thing that matters is $G$'s behavior on the image of $T$. Either it's injective on that image or it's not, and we have an argument in either case.

I am really sorry to still not get it. What is the argument if some $G_{\theta_1,\theta_2}$ is constant on some interval $[a,b]$ containing two distinct points of im($T$)?

@AnneBauval I have an argument in the case in which $T$ is required to be continuous. Suppose that $T(x_0)\in[a,b]$ and also that $T$ is continuous in $x_0$. This forces $F$ to be constant on a neighborhood of $x_0$, a contradiction. This, together with Greg's answer, proves the claim in the continuous case, and also in the almost everywhere continuous case, I believe. Any ideas for the measurable case?
